# rails ujs link_to for prompting error on a certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This maybe a simple question but i still cant find the answer

Basically, how do I have a link/button to prompt an error if it met a certain condition ?

With the example below, it will prompt on the link, but you can select yes/no.

```
<%= link_to 'Void', void_invoice_path(@invoice), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to void the invoice ?' } %>
```

Thats not what I want. For example in this case, void button/link cannot work if there exist payment. I would like to still allow the user to click on the link but a javascript error prompts up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to bind that behaviour on that link yourself like:

```
<%= link_to 'Void', void_invoice_path(@invoice), 
      data: { error: 'You are not allowed to void the invoice ?' } %>
```

and in application.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[data-error]').click(function(event){
    alert($(this).attr('data-error'))
    $(this).preventDefault()
  })
})
```

In terms of the the bound event needs to be delegated read: [Delegate Javascript! ...if you can.](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/02/delegate-javascript-if-you-can.html)